# how to hash SHA512 string in c #

Tags: c#

I have this  "mac key" and other parameter and I need it turned into SHA512

I really need working example code too

I've gathered that it might have something to do with System.Security.Cryptography's SHA512Managed class, but I don't understand how to use that class  for a c sharp website at all it makes no sense to me that is why I need a working example of it turning a string into SHA512

Comment: "I really need working example code too" isn't a nice way to ask others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is for sha256, guess you could turn it into sha512 easily.
Hope this will do the trick :)

`using System.Security.Cryptography;`

```
    public static String HashPassword(string p, string s)
    {
        var combinedPassword = String.Concat(p, s);
        var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedPassword);
        var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    public static String GetRandomSalt(Int32 size)
    {
        var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var salt = new Byte[size];
        random.GetBytes(salt);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
    }
```